# When validating a list index is it better to check for validity beforehand or catch and handle IndexError?

Tags: python, exception

What is the pythonic way for checking a user provided vector index?

```
def get_value(vector, index):
    try:
        return vector[index]
    except IndexError:
        raise ValueError('bad index')
```

or

```
def get_value(vector, index):
   if -1 < index < len(vector):
       return vector[index]
   else:
       raise ValueError('bad index')
```

Comment: By vector do you mean `list`?  If so, your second form is inappropriate because negative indexes into Python `list`s are allowed.  They retrieve from the end of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying first is more Pythonic. From the [glossary](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html):

> EAFP
>
> Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. This common Python coding style assumes   the existence of valid keys or attributes and catches exceptions if the assumption proves false. This clean and fast style is characterized by the presence of many try and except statements. The technique contrasts with the LBYL style common to many other languages such as C.

Although I wouldn't even put that around a `try`...`except` since you're just throwing an IndexError, which it already does.

Comment: yup exactly. A big difference compared to working in python vs C/C++/Java.

Comment: for those who don't realize LBYL = Look Before You Leap

Answer (score 1):

I think its reasonable to just let the `IndexError` propagate up to the user. The user is passing you an `index` into something. If its out of range `IndexError` is reasonably thrown from your interface. So I would just do:

```
def get_value(vector, index):
    """ gets value... throws IndexError() if index out of range"""
    return vector[index]
```

This also lets you use valid negative indices in your interface.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to let the `IndexError` be thrown -- it's an invalid request. Another is to do `vector.get(index)` which gives you a None type on failure (same as `try: return vector[index] except: return None`). It really depends on what you intend to do upon failure. If you want to request the user try again, then .get() or try except is probably best. Otherwise raising the exception up to the top level indicates the program can't handle the request.

Note that the "Pythonic" way would normally be a try except -- but I reiterate that it's much more dependent on your use case.